# Is the Method object equivalent to the Command object in the Command design pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, methods

I've just discovered about the existence of the Method class in Java.

Is an instance of this class equivalent to an instance of a Command class in the context of the Command design pattern?

If not, what are this class' practical uses?

Comment: Totally the wrong end of the stick. [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

Comment: Did you mean instance of class Method or a pattern element "Method object" ? If you mena first - answer is no. If you mean the second - answer is maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class, as well as the class [`Field`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html), class [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html), are all part of [reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/). This API is used to provide access to object in an indirect way.

The first idea behind reflection was to allow an object to describe itself. For instance an IDE could display all properties of an object for debugging, RAID development and so on.

If reflection is still used that way, it's also used today to discover dynamically the structure of an object or a class and "act on" it without explicitly knowing it : to change the values of its fields or invoke one its methods.

For instance, if you know class A, you can invoke the method m() of A this way :

```
A a = new A();
a.m();
```

With reflection, without knowing class A explicitly, you could :

```
Object a = A.getDeclaredConstructors()[0].newInstance();
Method m = a.getClass().getMethod("m");
m.invoke(a, null);
```

In the second case, you can imagine a more generic mechanism where you discover methods or fields and invoke them or change their values without knowing them in advance.

So, to answer directly your question, it has nothing to do with the Command design pattern.

Answer (score 3):

> Is an instance of this class equivalent to an instance of a Command class in the context of the Command design pattern?

No, absolutely not: `Method` class is part of reflection feature of Java. Command pattern, on the other hand, is language-agnostic, so it can be implemented in any language, including ones that lack reflection capabilities.

The practical use of the `Method` class is to access methods of classes to which you do not have access at compile time. You can load a class by name, grab its method object - also by name, and perform an invocation.

With this said, it does not mean that you couldn't implement something that behaves like the command pattern using reflection. In fact, you could make your implementation more flexible by eliminating compile-time dependency on your code. For example, you could build a system that take plugins, and requires that plugin classes implement a particular method. Rather than shipping to plugin writers an interface with the signature of the method, you could tell them that as long as their class implements the method that you need, the plugin is going to be accepted. At runtime you would be able to discover the proper method through reflection, and call user code without compile-time dependencies on either side.